# Jquery change script elements on browser width adjust

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to use matchMedia in Jquery so that the script will draw `smallBlock` when the browser is 479px wide or less and draw `largeBlock` on every other size.

Here is the full script code: The first part of the script is TweenMax and the second part is my script. https://jsfiddle.net/h0eu0edd/

You can see the rectangle being drawn on here (http://imdarrien.com/#)

```
  function handleScreen(mql) {
   if (mql.matches) {
       smallBlock();
   } else {
       largeBlock();
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few syntax errors in the code you posted to jsfiddle.

Also, I changed the code to use `$(document).ready` instead of `$(window).load` as jsfiddle doesn't handle it.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/w1xnsgcg/

Comment: Ah I see thank you. :) Is there any reason why matchMedia still doesn't work?

Comment: As far as I can tell it looks like it's working in the jsfiddle link that I gave you. When I resize the screen, the correct block is getting invoked.